# Send custom list from java to jquery, cannot find the values

Tags: java, jquery, cordova

I'm overriding the cordova execute method trying to get a custom list back to the index.js file

The callback sends a JSONObject so i'm trying to convert my custom list into that object and doing so by just looping the orders list like so:
(I have just included the most important lines to show how i populate the json object, there is more in the real method)
The problem is in jquery where i receive the object, i can print out the key just fine but cannot find the values!. What should i do?

```
List<OrderDto> theOrders = service.getOrders();

JSONObject sendObj = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i < theOrders.size(); i++) {
    sendObj.put(Integer.toString(i), theOrders.get(i));
    System.out.println("PRINTING OUT ORDERNO: " + theOrders.get(i).OrderNo); // Works just fine!
}

callbackContext.success(sendObj);
return true;
```

Example of jquery callback method:

```
var success = function (recivedObj) {
   $.each(recivedObj, function(key, val) {
      alert('key: ' + key + ' val.OrderNo: ' + val[key].OrderNo);
   });
}
```

I have tried all sorts of val.Something and it's always undefined, or nothing at all shows up and when looking at sendObj  in debugger it's clear that it contains the values i need br> but it looks like the values is under something like:
nameValuePairs.table[2].value.OrderDto.OrderNo so how to find them in jquery?

Since it's eclipse and the code runs in emulator it's imposible to debug!!!